# JQuery поочередная отправка $.get / $.post

Tags: jquery, post, javascript, get

Есть такой код

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  $.getJSON('export.php',
             i,
             function(data){console.log(data);} 
           );
}
```

И все запросы летят одновременно, как сделать так чтобы они выполнялись поочередно, друг за другом.

Answer (score 2):

```
var f_list = $.Deferred().resolve();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        f_list = f_list.pipe(function() {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            $.getJSON('export.php', i, function(data) {
                dfd.resolve();
            });

            return dfd.promise();
        });
    })(i);
}

$.when(f_list).done(function(){
    console.log('done!');
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Хотя по идее `ajax` тоже должен возвращать `Deferred`, но я хз, т.е.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        f_list = f_list.pipe(function() {
            return $.getJSON('export.php', i, function(data) {
                console.log(i);
            });
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Как оказалось все гораздо проще. Перед циклом добавил 
>$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
и все работает как часы =) 
Спасибо всем

Comment: ну да, я совсем забыл про async )

Comment: @Алексей Дорохов так страница же полностью блокируется. Ну вам виднее, как лучше :)

Comment: В мозилле и опере скрипт отрабатывает отлично. =) Спасибо, за то теперь много инфы про дефферед )

Answer (score 1):

может как то так:

```
function send(num){
    $.getJSON('export.php',
        num,
        function(data){
           if (num < 99)
             send(num+1)
           console.log(data);
        } 
    );
}
send(0);
```